# how to make double sided images

Tags: java

I am trying to create a card game that will take 2 cards from the deck and flip them at the same time to reveal which card it is only for a few seconds then flip them back over but im having trouble with getting the cards p know they have a front and back. Right now i have a deck and the 2 cards but they are all up right i need the deck to be facing down and the 2 cards to also be facing down installing then be flipped. But when i load the back picture it just makes all the cards the same picture. I know i have to set it up in the deck class with some sort of flag but just dont know how?

```
    public class Deck 
    {
        private  Random random = new Random (); 
        protected Card cards[] = new Card[52] ; 

        private ImageIcon back = new ImageIcon("card bitmaps/back.GIF"); 
        protected boolean flip = false; 
        protected int numcards = 0; 

        public Deck()
        {
            int i = 0; 
            for (int s = 1; s<5 ; s++)
            {
                for (int n=1; n<14 ; n++)
                {
                    cards[i] = new Card(n,s);
                    i++; 
                    numcards =  numcards + 1; 
                }
            }

        }

        public void giveslapZone (Deck d) 
        {
            numcards = numcards - 1; 
            d.takecardslapZone(cards[numcards]); 
            return; 
        }

        public void takecardslapZone(Card c)
        {
            cards[numcards] = c;
            numcards = numcards + 1;

        }



         public void shuffle ()
        {

             for (int i = 0; i<numcards; i++)
             {
                 int j = random.nextInt(numcards);
                 Card temp = cards[i]; 
                 cards[i] = cards[j];
                 cards[j] = temp;

             }
        }



        public void draw (Container c ,Graphics g, int x , int y  )
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<numcards; i++)
            {
                 cards[i].draw(c, g, x,y) ; 
                 if (flip==false)
                 back.paintIcon(c,g,x,y); 
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this through as in real world. Which object has images on two sides ?`Card`. So your target object is `Card` and not `Deck`.
Now, how to design class `Card` that can have to images ? Simply by adding references to the image it should hold as :

```
public class Card  { //extends/implements etc
  private Image frontImage;  //Image with number etc.
  private Image backImage;   //Image shown when the card is faced down.
  //--and so on..
```

Now, in your flipping animation, you need to draw the card using images for either side depending up on which side is shown to the user. Also, one quick note. Given that the back image in most of the cards decks are same, use a static final Image to hold the global backImage and re-use it on all cards.

Comment: So why have an actual instance field pointing to the back image in the first place?

Comment: You have to `encapsulate` a card's property with in a card. By making this information external, its open to be changed from everywhere - like in this example, and that's the reason why it is drawing same image for both cards.

Comment: I'm not saying it should be outside of the `Card` class or that it should be public. I'm saying it should not be an *instance* field. Note: I'm not the OP.

Comment: OK agree that `backImage` is not "needed" as an instance field. We can have it or not. It does not mage a difference either way. If I were to code, I would still use a instance field that points to a global value.  I think that example holds good for the explanation I gave for modelling. Just below that I had added that we could use a global image instead.